# How delete data from CollectionTable | Hibernate (Jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uielementcollection

i have "A" entity with `List<String> MyList`:

```
@Entity(name = "A_table")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String RepresentativeName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "MyList_Table")
    private List<String> MyList;
}
```

After i set Values to this "A" entity, i want to delete all this data from the derby table.
But how i can delete the Strings from the CollectionTable (MyList_Table)?

I try to make it by HQL query, but i got error.

```
List<String> strList = em.createQuery("from MyList_Table").getResultList();
...
...
```

the Error:

```
MyList_Table is not mapped [from MyList_Table]
```

**How should I formulate the query correctly?

There may be another way to delete this CollectionTable data?**

**--------------------------------**
**Update:**

when i used :
`List<A> objectList = em.createQuery("from A_table").getResultList();`
-> i got error :
`A_Table is not mapped [from A_Table]`.

So I decided to leave this line as it was:
`List<A> objectList = query.getResultList()`.
But then, if i try to delete it:

```
for (A a:objectList)
{
   if(....)
   {
     List<String> Mylist = a.getMyList();
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.remove(Mylist);
      em.getTransaction().commit();
   }
}
```

i get an error :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
```

So i try to add `"@IndexColumn`" annotation :

```
    .....
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_Table")
    @IndexColumn(name= "indx")
    private List<String> MyList;
    ...
```

and now i get this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList
```

**what i should do?**

Thank you very much!!

Comment: **The solution is here:**

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920323/how-to-delete-data-from-org-hibernate-collection-persistentbag-hibernate-jpa/23930146#23930146][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920323/how-to-delete-data-from-org-hibernate-collection-persistentbag-hibernate-jpa/23930146#23930146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must recover elements from your parent table, i.e. A:

```
List<A> objectList = em.createQuery("from A").getResultList(); 
// It would be neccesary to cast the result list
```

Once you have your result list, you can access now to your secondary table and do with these data whatever you want:

```
objectList.getMyList().clear();
...
```

If it doesn't work to you, you can use CriteriaQuery:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<A> objectList = query.getResultList();
```

EDIT: I have notice that you have a name attribute in your @Entity annotation, your mapping table is not named "A", but "A_table":

```
List<A> objectList = em.createQuery("from A_table").getResultList();
```

EDIT2: To delete elements, try deleting it one by one instead of deleting the entire list:

```
List<String> Mylist = a.getMyList();
em.getTransaction().begin();
for (String element:Mylist){
    em.remove(element);
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**---------------------------

The solution is here:**
[How to delete data from org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag? | Hibernate (Jpa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920323/how-to-delete-data-from-org-hibernate-collection-persistentbag-hibernate-jpa/23930146#23930146)

Comment: it's didnt help...
when i get into the first row(List<A> objectList = em.createQuery("from A").getResultList(); ) I still got ERROR:
A is not mapped [from A].
@Genzotto

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: A is not mapped [from A].

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you another way to recover data and a possible problem with your mapping

Comment: Okay, the second option does not returns me an error.  But the line: objectList.getMyList().clear(); does not delete the data from the CollectionTable..

Comment: your "Edit" caused an error:
A_Table is not mapped [from A_Table] @Genzotto

Comment: Use then the CriteriaBuilder solution to recover data. Do you want to delete data from database?

Comment: Yes, i need to delete this data from the data base. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920323/how-to-delete-data-from-org-hibernate-collection-persistentbag-hibernate-jpa?noredirect=1#comment36839951_23920323