# How to delete data from org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag? | Hibernate (Jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

The `List<String> Mylist` is `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag`...

and **i want to delete this Mylist**...
**How i can do it??**

```
QriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A_entity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A_entity.class);
criteriaQuery.from(A_entity.class);
Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<A_entity> queryList = query.getResultList();
for (A_entity a:queryList)
{
   if(....)
   {
     List<String> Mylist = a.func();
     ???How delete Mylist????
   }
}
```

**Thank you very much!!**

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can't delete a list. You can clear it, i.e. remove everything it contains, using the standard `clear()` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914149/how-delete-data-from-collectiontable-hibernate-jpa
as you can see this Mylist is ArrayList in entity,
so i want to delete this list data from the CollectionTable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting elements one by one:

```
List<String> Mylist = a.getMyList();
em.getTransaction().begin();
for (String element:Mylist){
    em.remove(element);
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**_______________________

The Solution (Work to me, thank to "Genzotto"):**

```
List<String> Mylist = a.getMyList();
listStirng.clear();
em.getTransaction().begin();
     for (String str : Mylist) {
         em.merge(str);
     }
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: i get an error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.String. @Genzotto

Comment: You should check your mappings and make sure they are correct. You can also clear the list (using clear() method), and then updating your A element with em.merge(object_of_A_class)

Comment: gooooooddd!!!!
i clear the list (using clear() method), and then updating your A element with em.merge(object_of_A_class) and it's work!!! thank!!!!